# business generated has to come based on dcr(daily call report)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have **DCR & SalesMIS model**. I want to get the business generated count. And if count is it should return the `business_genrated` else `saleMIS.amount`

I wrote a method in `DCR` model i.e. `get_business_generated(self)` and apply filter on `SaleMIS` model. Then trying to get the count of `business_generated`

> ERROR:D:\Projects\Python\Django\kingllp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 95, in **new**
>       "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
>   RuntimeError: Model class builtins.DCR doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

This is DCR model

```
class DCR(models.Model):

    STATUSES = (
        ('1N', 'Need Analysis'),
        ('2P', 'Proposal Stage'),
        ('3C', 'Competitive Selling'),
        ('4D', 'Decision Stage'),
    )
    prospect = models.ForeignKey(Prospect, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dcrs')
    date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUSES, max_length=2, default='1N')
    discussion_points = models.CharField(max_length=2047, blank=True)
    business_generated = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_new_business = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def get_business_generated(self):
        date = self.date
        client = self.prospect

        sale = SalesMIS.objects.filter(date=date,client = Prospect)
        salecount = sale.count()
        if salecount==0:
            return DCR.business_generated
        else: 
            return SalesMIS.amount
```

This is **SaleMIS** model

```
class SalesMIS(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Sale MIS")

    date = models.DateField()
    fls = models.ForeignKey(Employee, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='sales')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='client_mis')


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + ":" + self.fls.full_name()
```

Business share has to come based on `DCR/MIS`.

Comment: The error suggests a problem with INSTALLED_APPS in your settings file, or perhaps the way the app is structured.  Can you post details of those.

Comment: setting.py INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'import_export',

    'call.apps.CallConfig',
    'client.apps.ClientConfig',
    'employee.apps.EmployeeConfig',
 'report.apps.ReportConfig',
    'drf_yasg',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'rest_framework',
 'notification.apps.NotificationConfig'
]

Comment: from django.db import models
from client.models import Lead, Prospect
from report.models import SalesMIS
from django.db.models import Count

Comment: DCR is the model mentioned in the error message.  Which app is that defined in?

Comment: DCR is the model in CALL app